# Iterating through PersistentSet in a JPA property setter while loading the Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When I do

```java
entityManager.find(Human.class, 1)
```

, the `forEach` or any read-only operation on `names` in the setter `setNames(Set<String>)` causes the error below. However, in both

```java
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.find(Human.class, 1);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

```java
entityManager.find(Human.class, 1).forEach(System.out::println);
//setNames(Set<String>) changed to this.names = names
```

, the error disappears, and 2 `select` statements are executed. Why is read-only operation disallowed in a JPA property setter?

I am using property-based access to loop through the elements because I want to deserialize the set of String values before being added to the `Human` class. If this issue cannot be solved, could there be a replacement solution?

```java
@Entity
public class Human {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();

    @ElementCollection
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public Set<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }


    public void setNames(Set<String> names) {
        names.forEach(this.names::add);
    }

}
```

```
org.hibernate.sql.exec.ExecutionException: A problem occurred in the SQL executor : Error advancing (next) ResultSet position
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.makeExecutionException(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.lambda$processNext$0(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advance(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:437)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4313)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4303)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:598)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1237)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1225)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.loader.access.IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:2331)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:2293)
    at codemetry.nettitalks/test.Test.join(Test.java:59)
    at codemetry.nettitalks/test.Test.main(Test.java:49)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error advancing (next) ResultSet position
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:485)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:1802)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.1.1.Final/org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.lambda$processNext$0(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:89)
    ... 99 more
```

Comment: `names.forEach(this.names::add)` - you are forcing HBN to initialize `PersistentSet` when it is in process of initializing entity (issue another one sql query, process resultset, etc) - may be HBN do not expect that, may be mysql jdbc driver fails somewhere. How are you going to transform `names`?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov In my real case, it's `Set<Permission>` instead of `Set<String>` (to simplify the question), where `Permission` is a common interface for multiple enum classes. Since I cannot persist an interface type, I chose property-based access to convert the set to `Set<PermissionEntry>` where `PermissionEntry` is an Embeddable class storing the enum's declaring class and ordinal for persisting, and vice versa for loading. Is this an appropriate approach, or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: have you considered `@Transient`: https://jdoodle.com/ia/tId ?